# Setup new router with SQM - Buffer Bloating solution

Tags: router, ping, latency, isp

Scenario. I'm in Tbilisi, Georgia.
I have very **high ping to EU servers**(100ms+) plus a huge **buffer bloating problem**, this test gave me the F rank: https://www.waveform.com/tools/bufferbloat
I use an optical Fiber connection, 100 Mbps connection from Magti ISP and fiber connection PC <-> Router.

I can't solve the high ping issue, but I can solve the Buffer Bloating.

I have a router or modem from the ISP. The router is locked and I can access it only with help of the ISP support. No login details at all.
The ISP router model name is unknown. There is no S/N or vendor name at all.

I found that **UISP EdgeRouter X** has SQM support so it can manage the buffer bloating.
But this router doesn't have the Fiber input as far as I know.

**The question is.** If I will buy the UISP router, then connect it to the original router from the ISP, and set up the SQM, will I solve the Buffer Bloating issue or I will face new problems + the same issues + some latencies?

p.s. I'm a complete newbie here, please don't be harsh :>

Comment: This belongs on [su].

Comment: Sorry, my bad, will post another question there